# Programmatically install packages with Yarn using node.js

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

I'm building something that needs to call `yarn` from within a node program itself, is this possible? I've not found anything reasonable online besides calling `yarn install` by using `child_process` and calling the shell command.

While I know this will work, I'd rather have a way to call the Yarn API directly from within my node application, how can I do something like this?

Comment: Not currently. See issues [#906](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/906) and [#4514](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4514).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run \`yarn tag\` programmatically from node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250231/how-to-run-yarn-tag-programmatically-from-node-js)

Comment: No, I think I want to avoid calling exec or sending shell commands, want to interact directly with yarn.