# Run a set of yarn commands sequentially in a node script

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I want to use yarn commands sequentially and run it in a node script, in the intermediate steps, and mix it with js as needed. For example

```
yarn audit > out.json

//some file reading, processing, and storage

for(i = 0; i < libs.length; i++) {

    yarn add lib1@v1.1.1 //need to run this in a loop
    //print the console output as this is being done
}
```

Is the above possible in node js or any other script that can be used in a node project?

Comment: i had tried suggestion from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250231/how-to-run-yarn-tag-programmatically-from-node-js, but does not work well, exits soon or errors

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously
You can execute commands using `child_process`